# Is it safe to update from lubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, lubuntu

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** on my old thinkpad laptop, to improve the performance of the system i replaced unity desktop with **lubuntu desktop** and now my system is running fast compared with unity desktop which comes with stock Ubuntu 14.04. Now when i check for updates using software&updates i get a update telling system is ready to upgrade from 14.04 to **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Is it safe to update? Do i need to revert back from lubuntu desktop to unity before i proceed ? I am worried that if something go wrong i will be forced to fresh install Ubuntu and need to spent hours of time to setting up required packages which i use. Please recommend . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience i recommend not to update from lubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. After i started the update process, everything went fine all the packages are downloaded and extracted, everything was okay and the system is ready for reboot, instead of reboot the system got stuck at home screen with out  task bar, launchpad and is complete unresponsive. I tried to start gnome full screen terminal and also tried to safe restart - noting worked and forced me to shutdown by long pressing the power button.

After i started system back everything was only blank screen with blinking cursor. I tried to start in recovery mode, tried to fix broken packages from grub- noting worked, so finally booted Ubuntu with bootable usb and retrieved all my important files and fresh installed the Ubuntu 16.04.

So i recommend to replace lubuntu desktop with Unity before updating, which i have not tested but i think it is way to update.